# How do I find out how many FPS I am getting in a game?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Is there any way to find out how many FPS I am getting in a game?  For instance, is there any free software or mods I can download that will tell me this? I am playing MW3, but it could be general software, as well.

Answer (score 3):

There's no generic way to perfectly determine the exact fps a game (or program in general) is rendering, unless the game or program provides that information itself (which could be faked or inaccurate as well).

The most generic approach I can think of would be using a tool such as [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/), which will show a generic fps counter in supported programs (DirectX and OpenGL). The free version is perfectly sufficient for this.

However, you'll have to consider one important thing: Fraps only counts the final frames that are shown on screen. Theoretically, it's possible that the game updates with like 20 or 30 frames per second, but renders the result with 30 or 60 fps. In this case Fraps would still show 30/60 fps, despite the game running at a lower rate.

For this specific case:

You can tell MW3 to display the fps by setting `cg_drawFPS 1` in your `config_mp.cfg`.

Comment: cg_drawFPS not working in MW3.